# Preserve column names when groupby and collect_list with array_zip in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    Row(foo='a', bar=1, baz=4),
    Row(foo='a', bar=2, baz=5),
    Row(foo='b', bar=3, baz=6),
])
```

The result of the above looks like:

```
[Row(bar=1, baz=4, foo='a'), Row(bar=2, baz=5, foo='a'), Row(bar=3, baz=6, foo='b')]
```

I need to group on `foo` and then collect everything else as lists. The results need to preserve the same name as the columns from which they are derived.

So far, I've got this:

```
df.groupBy('foo').agg(
    F.arrays_zip(
        F.collect_list(F.col('bar')),
        F.collect_list(F.col('baz')),
    ).alias('events')
)
```

The output returns a dataframe where the `events` column holds Rows, each of which has keys that increment `0`, `1`, `2`, etc.

```
[Row(foo='a', events=[Row(0=1, 1=4), Row(0=2, 1=5)]), Row(foo='b', events=[Row(0=3, 1=6)])]
```

I would like to instead preserve the original column names as the keys. Such that a row such as `Row(0=1, 1=4)` would instead be `Row(bar=1, baz=4)`. How might this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply collect list of structs instead of creating 2 array columns and zip them:

```
df1 = df.groupBy('foo').agg(
    F.collect_list(
        F.struct(
            F.col('bar'), 
            F.col('baz')
        )
    ).alias("events")
)

print(df1.collect()) 

# [Row(foo='a', events=[Row(bar=1, baz=4), Row(bar=2, baz=5)]), Row(foo='b', events=[Row(bar=3, baz=6)])]
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to break this into 2 steps:

```
df.groupBy('foo').agg(
    F.collect_list(F.col('bar')).alias('bar'),
    F.collect_list(F.col('baz')).alias('baz'),
).withColumn(
    'events',
    F.arrays_zip(
        F.col('bar'),
        F.col('baz'),
    )
).drop('bar', 'baz').collect()
```

Which resulted in:

```
[Row(foo='a', events=[Row(bar=2, baz=5), Row(bar=1, baz=4)]), Row(foo='b', events=[Row(bar=3, baz=6)])]
```